# How do I list all categories tree in layred navigation in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can I list all categories tree in layered navigation? Right now when I click on a parent category its subcategories are listed only.

Also can I filter products on multiple attributes. For example shirts of color red, black and green.

Above things possible in Magento with some coding or do I have to purchase an extension or is there any free extension that improves layred navigation?

Comment: What I did so far is created a block that lists all categories above layered navigation. Layered navigation is filtering products now. Still a few problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do all these things through your admin panel
go to catalog->manage catagories and add sub catagories there... save it. you can see the changes in the front end of magento then....